# Maximum value of tokens per purchase - BSC - Solidity

Tags: ethereum, binance-smart-chain

I am studying a solidity code and it has the following excerpt. The maximum that can be purchased is 5 tri at a time. For me to increase the value that can be purchased at a time, should I change the values of the function "numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity"?

In other words: I would like to have a purchase limit higher than that of 5tri, or even take it off.

```
address[] private _excluded;
uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
uint256 private _tTotal = 1000000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
uint256 private _tFeeTotal;
string private _name = "NAME";
string private _symbol = "NAME";
uint8 private _decimals = 9;
uint256 public _taxFee = 2;
uint256 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
uint256 public _liquidityFee = 3;
uint256 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
bool inSwapAndLiquify;
bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 5000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
uint256 private numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = 500000 * 10**6 * 10**9;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show a minimal **reproducible** code example. This is a list of properties, possibly from multiple contracts (one contract would not allow re-declaring the `_rTotal`), and we are not able to see the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity` just tells the contract when to swap and liquify (the `auto-liquidity` feature). In your case, every 5 tril transactions, the contract will sell half of its holdings to BNB and add the two halves as liquidity. This has nothing to do with the max transaction amount. You can just change that to whatever you want. You can also just set it to your supply (one quadrillion) if you don't want a limit to be imposed on transactions.